# how to take an average of multiple numbers?

Tags: r, excel, function, excel-formula

I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem I am having in Excel (or R) . Here's an example of my data, say I have

```
Date                     NumBirds
January/1/2010           20
January/1/2010           22
January/1/2010           5
January/2/2010           15
January/2/2010           12
January/3/2010           7
January/3/2010           20
```

And I want to take an average of birds observed on each day so for

January/1/2010 I have average(20,22,5) = 15.667

January/2/2010 I have average(15,12) = 13.5

January/3,2010 I have average(7,20) = 13.5

I have tried if function but I can't get it to work. I might be doing something really wrong. Please Help
Thank you,
Ana

Comment: If you are using excel this is easy. Lookup how to use pivot tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Daniel Williams:

[image: SO21692523 example]

One advantage of a PT is its versatility, shows average by date (and in total) but can easily be adjusted to show much more also.

Answer (score 1):

In R this will do the trick:

```
f<-read.table("clipboard",header=T) # I used ctrl+c on your data to use this "clipboard feature

tapply(f$NumBirds, f$Date, mean)
```

Here is the output:

```
January/1/2010 January/2/2010 January/3/2010 
      15.66667       13.50000       13.50000
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know I didnt think of the tapply function! Anyways I figured out in Excel I need to use AVERAGEIF function, if you ever run into this problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

use formula like this

```
=AVERAGE(D2:D4)
```

where D2 is the start cell of your data and D4 is the ending cell

type the code into the cell you want the average to come up in.

Please thumb up for good answer :)

Comment: Thank you but it gets really hard to do when I have over 100 values I want to average. I just figured out that I need to use and 'AVERAGEIF' function.Thank you though.